# ¿como puedo transformar un input date a la edad de un usuario?

Tags: javascript, html, date, condiciones, while

mi problema consta en que tengo que imprimir los datos de un formulario HTML y javascript en un  `<h1>` pero con el input  `date` tengo que pasarlo a la edad que tenga el usuario según los datos que introdujo, mi duda es como enviar todos los datos al  `<h1>` y transformar los datos introducidos en  `date` a la edad que el usuario aya introducido.

Usando las funciones While y if.

mi código HTML es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="work js/form.js"></script>
    <title>formulario</title>
    <link href="rcss/" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="cabeza">
        <form action="" id="formulario">
        <p id="boton">
        <label id="engreso"for="">ingrese sus datos</label>
        </p>
        <p id="nombre">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="sendit">
        </p>
        <p id="apellido">
        <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" class="sendit">
        </p> 

        <p id="fecha">
            <input type="date" name="fecha" class="sendit">

        </p> 

        <p id="email">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Example@mailserv.com" class="sendit">

        </p>    

        <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="boton" onclick="send()">

    </form>
    </div>    
     <div id="cuerpo">
    <h1 id="yax">Cuales son sus datos</h1>
    <h1 id="nom">Su nombre</h1>
    <h1 id="yax">Cual es su apellido</h1>
    <h1 id="ape">su apellido</h1>
    <h1 id="yax">Cual es su edad</h1>
    <h1 id="eda">su edad</h1>
    <h1 id="yax">Cual es su correo</h1>
    <h1 id="eda">su email</h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

y lo que tengo en el código javascript es:

```
function send(){
  var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario')[0];
  var elementos = formulario.elements;

  x=0;
  var fechas = document.getElementsByName('fecha')
  while( x < formulario){





    x++

  }

}
```

en resumen lo que tiene que hacer la función es que mediante lo que el usuario introduzca en input date lo convierta a su edad y imprimir los otros datos como nombre, apellido, etc, en un `<h1>`
muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una función que se encargue de procesar la **fecha** del **input** para después calcular la **edad**.

Después al **h1** con el **id="eda"** le asignamos que `innerHTML` sea igual a la **edad**.

Para que esto función es necesario que se le agregue un evento **change** al input date para cuando este cambie corra dicha función que lleva como parámetro el elemento `onchange="edad(event)"`.

```js
function edad(e) {
  edadMS = Date.parse(Date()) - Date.parse(e.target.value);
  edads = new Date();
  edads.setTime(edadMS);
  resultado = edads.getFullYear() - 1970;
  res = (resultado <= 0) ? 0 : resultado; // Para evitar que sea negativo
  document.getElementById('eda').innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
    <div id="cabeza">
        <form action="" id="formulario">
            <p id="fecha">
                <input type="date" onchange="edad(event);" name="fecha" class="sendit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="cuerpo">
        <h1 id="yax">Cual es su edad</h1>
        <h1 id="eda">su edad</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: como lo pudiese activar luego de clickear un botón?

Comment: Tendrías que quitar el onchange en input date y poner onclick en el botón, pero en lugar de mandar el evento dentro de la función lo mandarías vacío. En la función en lugar de usar e.target.value, usaras document.getElementByID('iddelinputdate').value.